# Passing a Template pointer to memcpy

Tags: c++, templates, memcpy

Why does the following not compile:

```
struct Carrier
{
  void* data;
  int StrategyRequestType;

  Carrier(int StrategyRequestType )
  {
    StrategyRequestType = StrategyRequestType;
  }

  template <typename T>
  bool loadStrategyRequestType(T)
  {
    data = malloc(sizeof(T));
    memcpy ( data, &T, sizeof(T) );   // Syntax error here - "expected primary expression before ',' token"
    return true;
  }
};
```

What is a way to make it work ?

Comment: Can you share the error message with us?

Comment: Hey Spook, I just did (updated the code with the error)

Comment: mmm... what is the point of this function? You allocate memory, fill it and then forget it? It gives you a memory leak and that's it...

Comment: BTW: why `malloc()` and not `new`?

Comment: T is a typename, not a variable. therefore address of T (&T) does not make sense

Comment: @glglgl I will add the destructor soon enuf .. Also, I am assured that the data is going to be POD.

Comment: "the data is going to be POD" — mention it in the question itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
template <typename T>
  bool loadStrategyRequestType(T)
  {
    data = malloc(sizeof(T));
    memcpy ( data, &T, sizeof(T) );   // Syntax error here - "expected primary expression before ',' token"
    return true;
  }
```

You can not take a pointer to a type. If you want to copy object t to data, do it like this :

```
template <typename T>
  bool loadStrategyRequestType(T t)
  {
    data = malloc(sizeof(T));
    memcpy ( data, &t, sizeof(T) );
    return true;
  }
```

The above may work ok, but it still may do copying when creating objects. Since, the object is not changed, this would be better in order to be sure no object is copied :

```
template <typename T>
  bool loadStrategyRequestType(const T& t)
  {
    data = malloc(sizeof(T));
    memcpy ( data, &t, sizeof(T) );
    return true;
  }
```

---

As I mentioned in comments, when implementing function templates, if c++11 is available, it is best to use universal reference. Why? Because they cover every possible case.

```
template <typename T>
  bool loadStrategyRequestType(T&& t)
  {
    data = malloc(sizeof(T));
    memcpy ( data, &t, sizeof(T) );
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: I suppose `T t` should be function argument

Comment: here as well: a `T* loadStrategyRequestType(T t)` would probably make more sense. And more error checking after `malloc()`.

Comment: @Lashane Ok, that makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: @glglgl `template <typename T> bool loadStrategyRequestType(T &&t)` would be even better. Not sure why it needs to return pointer.